# List dates between two dates and divide the amount associated with new date to respective dates and id R/PYTHON/EXCEL

Tags: mysql, r, excel, data-analysis

My data looks like this. I counted the difference between check in date and check out date to get number of days and based on days I will divide "Value" to each respective date. For ex. ID 3222808 had a stay of 2 days, so I will divide value 458/2 and assign it to each date. How do I do that in R or excel.

```
ID  Value   Checkin Checkout
3222808 458 11/15/2019  11/17/2019
606203  238 10/28/2019  10/30/2019
334229  218 11/16/2019  11/18/2019
837066  218 11/16/2019  11/18/2019
620384  218 11/16/2019  11/18/2019
534690  218 11/16/2019  11/18/2019
3192449 298 11/16/2019  11/18/2019

df <- structure(list(ID = c(3222808L, 606203L, 334229L, 837066L, 620384L, 
  534690L, 3192449L), Value = c(458L, 238L, 218L, 218L, 218L, 218L, 
  298L), Checkin = structure(c(18215, 18197, 18216, 18216, 18216, 
  18216, 18216), class = "Date"), Checkout = structure(c(18217, 
  18199, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218), class = "Date")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Output should look like:

```
ID  Value   Date 
3222808 229 11/15/2019  
3222808 229 11/16/2019
```

Code I am using currently is giving me this -

```
library(dplyr)

pm <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(
    data.frame(.[1:2], date = seq(.$Checkin, .$Checkout, by = "1 day"))
  )

Patron  Value   date
3222808 458 11/15/2019
3222808 458 11/16/2019
3222808 458 11/17/2019
606203  238 10/28/2019
606203  238 10/29/2019
606203  238 10/30/2019
334229  218 11/16/2019
```

From here, I do not know how to group them and divide the amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming that each stay has its unique `ID`* this can be solved by grouping by `ID` *and* by the mean `Value` and creating a sequence of days from `Checkin` date to the day before `Checkout` for each group:

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Date = seq(Checkin, Checkout - 1L, by = "1 day")), 
          by = .(ID, Value = Value / as.numeric(Checkout - Checkin))]
```

> ```
>          ID Value       Date
>  1: 3222808   229 2019-11-15
>  2: 3222808   229 2019-11-16
>  3:  606203   119 2019-10-28
>  4:  606203   119 2019-10-29
>  5:  334229   109 2019-11-16
>  6:  334229   109 2019-11-17
>  7:  837066   109 2019-11-16
>  8:  837066   109 2019-11-17
>  9:  620384   109 2019-11-16
> 10:  620384   109 2019-11-17
> 11:  534690   109 2019-11-16
> 12:  534690   109 2019-11-17
> 13: 3192449   149 2019-11-16
> 14: 3192449   149 2019-11-17
> ```

#### `dpylr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Value = Value / as.numeric(Checkout - Checkin)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = seq(Checkin, Checkout - 1L, by = "1 day") %>% list()) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(Date) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("Check"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 14 x 3
> # Groups:   ID, Value [7]
>         ID Value Date      
>      <int> <dbl> <date>    
>  1 3222808   229 2019-11-15
>  2 3222808   229 2019-11-16
>  3  606203   119 2019-10-28
>  4  606203   119 2019-10-29
>  5  334229   109 2019-11-16
>  6  334229   109 2019-11-17
>  7  837066   109 2019-11-16
>  8  837066   109 2019-11-17
>  9  620384   109 2019-11-16
> 10  620384   109 2019-11-17
> 11  534690   109 2019-11-16
> 12  534690   109 2019-11-17
> 13 3192449   149 2019-11-16
> 14 3192449   149 2019-11-17
> ```

#### Non-unique `ID`

In case `ID` is *not* uniquely identifying each stay but is a kind of customer id which may appear more than once in the dataset it is necessary to refine the grouping. `seq()` is not vectorized and will throw an error, otherwise.

For the `data.table` approach, `rowid()` can be used to force unique groups:

```
setDT(df2)[, .(Date = seq(Checkin, Checkout - 1L, by = "1 day")), 
          by = .(ID, ID_sub = rowid(ID), Value = Value / as.numeric(Checkout - Checkin))]
```

> ```
>          ID ID_sub Value       Date
>  1: 3222808      1   229 2019-11-15
>  2: 3222808      1   229 2019-11-16
>  3:  606203      1   119 2019-10-28
>  4:  606203      1   119 2019-10-29
>  5:  334229      1   109 2019-11-16
>  6:  334229      1   109 2019-11-17
>  7:  837066      1   109 2019-11-16
>  8:  837066      1   109 2019-11-17
>  9:  620384      1   109 2019-11-16
> 10:  620384      1   109 2019-11-17
> 11:  534690      1   109 2019-11-16
> 12:  534690      1   109 2019-11-17
> 13: 3192449      1   149 2019-11-16
> 14: 3192449      1   149 2019-11-17
> 15:  606203      2   119 2019-10-28
> 16:  606203      2   119 2019-10-29
> ```

Please, note that a modified dataset is used which includes a duplicate `ID` (see the *Data* section below).

For the `dplyr` approach, `rowwise()` can be used to group by rows:

```
df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Value = Value / as.numeric(Checkout - Checkin), 
         Date = seq(Checkin, Checkout - 1L, by = "1 day") %>% list()) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(Date) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("Check"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 16 x 3
>         ID Value Date      
>      <int> <dbl> <date>    
>  1 3222808   229 2019-11-15
>  2 3222808   229 2019-11-16
>  3  606203   119 2019-10-28
>  4  606203   119 2019-10-29
>  5  334229   109 2019-11-16
>  6  334229   109 2019-11-17
>  7  837066   109 2019-11-16
>  8  837066   109 2019-11-17
>  9  620384   109 2019-11-16
> 10  620384   109 2019-11-17
> 11  534690   109 2019-11-16
> 12  534690   109 2019-11-17
> 13 3192449   149 2019-11-16
> 14 3192449   149 2019-11-17
> 15  606203   119 2019-10-28
> 16  606203   119 2019-10-29
> ```

#### Data

This creates a dataset which contains a duplicated `ID`:

```
df2 <- rbind(df, df[df$ID == 606203, ])
```

Comment: Error in seq.POSIXt(Checkin, Checkout - 1L, by = "days") : 
  'from' must be of length 1

Comment: @amanda, the error message indicates that `ID` is not unique within your dataset (which was an assumption I had made from studying your sample dataset). However, I have added enhanced versions of the codes which can deal with duplicate `ID`. Please, give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main driver in this answer is `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(number_days = interval(Checkin, Checkout) %>%
           as.duration() %>%
           as.numeric("days")) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Checkin, Checkout), names_to = "names", values_to = "Date") %>%
  mutate_at("Value", ~(Value / number_days)) %>%
  filter(names == "Checkin") %>%
  select(ID, Value, Date)

>
# A tibble: 7 x 3
       ID Value Date      
    <int> <dbl> <date>    
1 3222808   229 2019-11-15
2  606203   119 2019-10-28
3  334229   109 2019-11-16
4  837066   109 2019-11-16
5  620384   109 2019-11-16
6  534690   109 2019-11-16
7 3192449   149 2019-11-16
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How can I exclude the checkout date in the list i am getting ? Goal is to calculate the difference between two dates and display dates excluding the check out date.

Comment: I added a filter line into the pipe to keep only "Checkin" rows.

Comment: Updated code is giving output - 
3222808 229 2019-11-15;;;
I want output to look like - 
3222808 229 2019-11-15;;;
3222808 229 2019-11-16;;;;
as checkin date is 15th November and checkout is 17th November. I want to display all the dates excluding checkout date.